# Set Regex in Flutter for phone number format

Tags: flutter

How i can prevent the user to insert Dot or comma or space in the TextFiled .. The user need to set 11 number (i.e 07956432101) to allow him to go the next page .. My code below ,, it didn't work using Flutter
any advice ...

```
final TextEditingController x = new TextEditingController();

String p = "[\,\.\s\-]";

void Send(String str) => setState(() {
RegExp _regExp = new RegExp(p);
if (x.text.isEmpty || x.text.length < 11 || x.text == _regExp) {
name2 = "Invalid phone Number !!! ";
} else
{
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
context, '/second', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
}
});

child: new TextField(
textInputAction: TextInputAction.go , 
controller: x,
keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
maxLength: 11,
maxLengthEnforced: true,
decoration: new InputDecoration(
icon: Icon(Icons.phone),
hintText: "Phone number",
),
onChanged: NewVlaue,
onSubmitted: Send, 
),
),
```